# getting datepicker is not a function as error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$(document).ready(
    /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
    function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
            changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
        });
    }
);
```

I am using datepicker for date selection. I have included the external js file for html page but its giving error like `type error $(..)datepicker is not function`.

Comment: Are you sure your Jquery loaded successfully?

Comment: Did you keep reference to your `datepicker` plugin..??

Comment: Please alert and comment the function be sure your jquery loaded

Comment: Please show the HTML section where you have included the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use jQuery User Interface Plugins you need to download [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download/)

After downloading it to your development environment you should add src to this file into your `index.html` file
`<script src="yourDestination/jquery-ui.min.js></script>`

And if this will not work again. Provide some Fiddle to see the problem

Comment: Yes i have added all the necessary Jquery user interface plugins                             <label>Enter the license active date</label><input type="text" id="datepicker" /><br>                                                                                              <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS  -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Load SCRIPT.JS which will create datepicker for input field  -->
    <script src="JS/script.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I get the error `'<blank> is not function'` it usually means I'm not importing the necessary code to make that function available.

Also, it can mean that I'm not invoking the function properly attached to the object.

When I'm not able to get a library function to work, I like to look at examples online for that function to see if I'm missing any other dependent libraries or necessary steps.

See if you have the necessary components that this example has located at https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we correct CDN url for jquery.js and  jquery-ui.js in your html page. we can get required result. Please try with correct following CDN urls:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>         
<!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS -->         
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

whole code will be like that
Your html page:

```
<html>  
<body>  
<label>Enter the license active date</label> 
<input type="text" id="datepicker" /><br>       
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>         
<!-- Load jQuery UI Main JS -->         
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>      
<!-- Load SCRIPT.JS which will create datepicker for input field -->
<script src="JS/script.js"></script>    
</body>     
</html>
```

and script.js file

```
$(document).ready(
    /* This is the function that will get executed after the DOM is fully loaded */
    function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,//this option for allowing user to select month
            changeYear: true //this option for allowing user to select from year range
        });
    }
);
```

Hope it will work for you.